# Centering dots under equality signs

Tags: equations, align

```
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
1+3=4 \\ 4+5=9 \\ 9+7=16 \\ 16+9=25
\end{align*}
```

I'm trying to put three vertical dots under these equalities. I have tried to use `\vdots`, but that failed. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Next time, please provide a **full** [minimum working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, including all the packages you load.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not too clear, where you want to place the dots (`\vdots`?).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  1+3&=4 \\
  4+5&=9 \\
  9+7&=16 \\
  16+9&=25 \\[-1ex]
  &\mathrel{
    \settowidth{\dimen0}{$=$}
    \hbox to \dimen0{\hss$\vdots$\hss}
  }
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\mathrel` assures the spacing as relational operator around the dots like the equals sign.
- The width of the equal sign is measured and the dots are placed in the center of a horizontal box with the same width as the equals sign.
- `[-1ex]` after `\\` reduces the vertical space a little.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps you want `\shortvdotswithin` (requires `mathtools`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 1+3 &=  4 \\
 4+5 &=  9 \\
 9+7 &= 16 \\
16+9 &= 25 \\
     &\shortvdotswithin{=}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 @egreg Is there a reason here for loading `amsmath` and `mathtools`? Just curious cause I've read barbara say that one should not load both together. Reference: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6319/is-a-showcase-of-preambles-off-topic/6329#comment18329_6319

Comment: @Milo Not everybody knows that `mathtools` loads `amsmath` and I recommend loading `amsmath` for every document that has math.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\overset` or `\underset` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
1 + 3 &\overset{\dots} {=} 4 \\[2mm]
4 + 5 &\underset{\dots}{=} 9 \\[2mm]
9 + 7 &                 = 16 \\[2mm]
16+ 9 &                 = 25 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: sorry I think I was not clear enough I want to use dots to go from up to down not from right to left. Sorry for misleading again and spending your time.